# Unable to add same option element to more than one dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have two dropdowns on a page. When a button is clicked I need a new option to be added to both dropdowns (same option to be added to both). The option values are stored in an array, I first create a new option element `new_option` and set its value/text from the array, and then the option gets added to the dropdown with `dropdown1_name.options.add(new_option)` and `dropdown2_name.options.add(new_option)`.

But in practice, the new option gets added only to the second dropdown I add it to but not the first, i.e. if I do dropdown2.add followed by dropdown1.add then only dropdown1 gets the new option.

It is easy to fix this by creating a replica of the new option element from scratch, and adding one copy to each dropdown. But that doesn't make sense to me so the point of this question is I would really like to understand what causes this behavior in the first place. Why can't the same newly created option be added to both dropdowns??

[This fiddle I just made](https://jsfiddle.net/vzf9t0or/) has a test setup.

Comment: this probably related with **deep copy vs shallow copy** search it online. You can use jquery https://api.jquery.com/clone/ or some other methods for generating a deep copy

Comment: You have to clone the node like "var cloneNode = el1.cloneNode(true);", you can;t add same instance at two element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is you are adding the same `<option>` instance to both dropdowns:

```
dropdown2.options.add(el1);
dropdown1.options.add(el1);
//                    ^^^ notice "el1" twice
```

Instead, you have to add `el2` to `dropdown2`:

```
dropdown2.options.add(el2);
dropdown1.options.add(el1);
```

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: As it's same instance so have to clone it and then you can add another dropdown.

Comment: But in this case, he had already created two instances of the option. The problem here is that he's adding the same instance to both dropdowns, leaving the second instance unused. EDIT: sorry, I just realized he was asking why he can't add the same instance, not why the demo code didn't work. So, yes, the answer is to clone the element :)